# $f(A-B)=f(A)-f(B)$ when f is an injection

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have $f:X\to Y$, an injection, and sets $A$ and $B$ subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Now I have to prove that

$$f(A-B)=f(A)-f(B).$$

I do know that they are not equal all the time; I came up with counter examples for that. However, I have an intuition that it may be a different case when f is injection, but I cannot even start my proof. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you prove an inclusion in one direction?

Comment: You mean either way of the two ways?

Comment: Yes. One of them doesn't involve the 1-1 assumption and it would be a good start.

Comment: Fist  of all B must be subset  of ${X}$ and can you plz define  the "-"function , what is exctaly the difference between two subsets  ?

Comment: i consider  that ${A}$ and ${B}$ are subsets of ${X}$ 
first i consider $ A \cap B = \emptyset \Rightarrow A-B =A$ $ \Rightarrow F(A-B) =F(A).$
$F(A)-F(B) =F(A$) because  $ A \cap B = \emptyset $ and F is injective which means $F(A) \cap F(B) =\emptyset$
then is$ F(A-B) = F(A)-F(B)$ when $ A\cap B = \emptyset$

Comment: now when  $ A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ ,

Comment: now when  $ A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ , $F(A-B) =\{ \exists y \in {Y},\exists x  \in{ A-B},F(x)=y\} \Leftrightarrow \{\exists y \in {Y}, \exists x \in {A} and x \not\in {B}, f(x) =y\} \Leftrightarrow \{\exists y \in {Y} ,\exists x \in {A},f(x)=y\} \cap \{\exists x \ not \in {B}, f(x) =y\} \Leftrightarrow  \{\exists y \in {Y},\exists x \in {A} ,y=f(x) , y \in {F({A})} \} \cap \{\exists x \not \in {B} ,f(x) =y , y  \not \in {F({B})} \} \Leftrightarrow  F({A}) - F({B})$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
f(x)\in f(A-B)&\Leftrightarrow x\in A-B\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in A \wedge x\notin B\\
&\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in f(A) \wedge f(x)\notin f(B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in f(A)-f(B)
\end{align*}
This proves the question.

Explanation:
1. Row: $x\in A\Rightarrow f(x)\in f(A)$ but $f(x)\in f(A)$ does not imply $x\in A$. If $f$ is injective then $f(x)\in f(A)$ imply $x\in A$. So $f(x)\in f(A)\Leftrightarrow x\in A$ when $f$ is injective.

3. Row: The fact that $x\notin B \Leftrightarrow f(x)\notin f(B)$ when $f$ is injective and 1. Row is used.