# For a bijective function show that

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f:A \to B$ be a bijective function such that $X \subset A$

Prove that $$f(A-X) = B -f(X) $$

Couldnt solve this question. Can someone please provide solution or some hint. Thank you

Comment: Whenever you want to show two sets are equal, take a member of the first, show it is in the second, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a bijection $\Rightarrow$ $f(A-X) \dot\bigcup f(X)=B$

Comment: That only shows one direction of the claim. Also, this isn't a proof.

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2680968/707884. you need $f$ only to be injective.

Comment: It is a hint and gives the right idea of what is going on to prove the claim above @DonThousand